# Does the global keyword inline the global exactly as a local variable declaration in python?

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, global

So are these two *exactly* equivalent vis a vis performance (that is, is the generated code exactly equivalent):

```
class A(object):
    const = 'abc'

    def lengthy_op(self):
        const = self.const
        for i in xrange(AVOGADRO):
            # do something which involves reading const
```

and:

```
const = 'abc'
class A(object):

    def lengthy_op(self):
        global const
        for i in xrange(AVOGADRO):
            # do something which involves reading const
```

Comment: If you are using variable in read-only manner you do not need global keyword. I'd expect dot access to be slightly slower, but answers to question like these are always "measure it". It's not very likely to be a performance bottleneck anyway.

Comment: @Rogalski: I know it's not needed -  my question is if it inlines the global in local scope (making it equivalent to the other). Dot access is performed once and global lookup also once - my question is are they equivalent afterwards - in the loop where just the name 'const' is used in both cases. This would be immediately answered by someone who can produce the bytecode, not by measuring, it should be definite - except if I miss something...

Comment: I'd expect the global access to be slower, since the variable name is first searched for in the symbol table of the local scope, and in the global only after nothing is found

Comment: Actually the `global` specifier, while unnecessary for correctness, might improve performance, since it will bypass any checks in the local scope.

Comment: @TomKarzes: exactly my point - now if we could remove that "might"...

Comment: If performance is really the issue, it might be cleaner to declare `const` where it makes the most sense, then make a local copy of it in the function outside of the loop.  But I have to wonder how much difference any of this will make in the performance.

Comment: @TomKarzes: it is a _language_ question - the gist of the question is if it makes difference or not on the underlying bytecode - I am fully aware of all the performance sayings - but I ask a definite question here. So back to the question: "it might be cleaner to declare const where it makes the most sense, then make a local copy of it in the function outside of the loop" - that's what I do - my question is if global creates a local copy - exactly equivalent to `const = self.const` or not. EDIT: question edited

Comment: As Donald Knuth once said: "premature optimization is the root of all evil". Choose the readable version regardless of performance, this won't make a noticable difference anyhow.

Comment: @Wolph: it does make a difference in this case (I have profiled the dot access and yes it makes a differnce which is a well known python fact) - as I said I am aware of kuhn's saying - is curiosity accepted as a motive of my question ? ;) That is I am curious to clarify the behavior of the glo0bal keyword (to proceed in refactoring some class variables to global scope where they belong in my case)

Comment: @Wolph: I edited the title to make it clearer I mainly ask for the behavior of the global keyword - performance being a consequence of the answer

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: curiosity is definitely an accepted motive by my standards. Note that I'm not saying that it doesn't make a measurable difference, I'm saying it makes no noticeable difference <in real world scenarios>. I'll add an explanation with some background info :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they are not *exactly* equivalent, although the difference is unlikely to be significant.

```
class A(object):
    const = 'abc'

    def lengthy_op(self):
        const = self.const
        for i in xrange(AVOGADRO):
            # do something which involves reading const
```

This creates a local variable so any access of const will use the `LOAD_FAST` opcode.

```
const = 'abc'
class A(object):

    def lengthy_op(self):
        # global const
        for i in xrange(AVOGADRO):
            # do something which involves reading const
```

This, with or without the redundant `global const` uses `LOAD_GLOBAL` to access the value of the global variables `const`, `xrange`, and `AVOGADRO`.

In C Python `LOAD_GLOBAL` will perform a fast dictionary lookup to access the variable (fast because the global variables are in a dictionary using only string keys and the hash values are pre-calculated). `LOAD_FAST` on the other hand simply accesses the first, second, third etc. local variables which is an array indexing operation.

Other versions of Python (e.g. PyPy) may be able to optimise accessing the global variable in which case there may not be any difference at all.

The first code (with `n=i+const` as the loop body) disassembles to:

```
>>> dis.dis(A.lengthy_op)
  5           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (const)
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (const)

  6           9 SETUP_LOOP              30 (to 42)
             12 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (xrange)
             15 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (AVOGADRO)
             18 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             21 GET_ITER            
        >>   22 FOR_ITER                16 (to 41)
             25 STORE_FAST               2 (i)

  8          28 LOAD_FAST                2 (i)
             31 LOAD_FAST                1 (const)
             34 BINARY_ADD          
             35 STORE_FAST               3 (n)
             38 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           22
        >>   41 POP_BLOCK           
        >>   42 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             45 RETURN_VALUE
```

while the second block gives:

```
>>> dis.dis(A.lengthy_op)
  5           0 SETUP_LOOP              30 (to 33)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (xrange)
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (AVOGADRO)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 GET_ITER            
        >>   13 FOR_ITER                16 (to 32)
             16 STORE_FAST               1 (i)

  7          19 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
             22 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (const)
             25 BINARY_ADD          
             26 STORE_FAST               2 (n)
             29 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
        >>   32 POP_BLOCK           
        >>   33 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             36 RETURN_VALUE
```

Python won't make a local copy of the global because there is no easy way to be sure that the global value won't change while the code is running. Anything, even another thread or a debugger, could modify the value while the loop is executing.

Comment: A ha - so adding the global keyword is not equivalent to `global const; local_const = const; # then use local_const`. Any reason why ? Would it not make sense the global declaration do this or it would break something ?

Comment: Python doesn't know that the global `const` won't vary so it can't just copy it, or at least not without doing other optimisations that the C implementation of Python doesn't do.

Comment: So bottom line what I was wondering is if global would just add an entry to the local variables given that it's read ony - edit: "Anything, even another thread or a debugger, could modify the value while the loop is executing" - excellent thanks that is what I was looking for :)

Comment: As for performance I bet without profiling that such differences would make a difference of a couple millenia for AVOGADRO :D Why is it that whenever a question on performance is asked people throw at you the Kuhn's saying as if you didn't know instead of looking at the question escapes me - hey guys performance is not a taboo, we are consenting adults here ;)

Comment: Actually I think you'll find your code throws either `TypeError: integer argument expected, got float` or `OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long` depending on the value of `AVOGADRO`. Upgrade to Python 3 and use `range()` and you might get it to work.

Comment: Haha - yes, I have actually fixed such a bug recently: https://github.com/wrye-bash/wrye-bash/commit/3993971214c4c4e19ee552d6c736bb2ff4f0bfcd#diff-9cce2419e77947d069ca14ed8543066bR4606 - in this case the fix would be `j=0; while j < AVOGADRO: ... ; j+=1` (but I probaly should use iterators for performance hahaha :D) Thanks again for answering me

Answer (score 0):

Whether it is faster or slower actually depends on your scope, the scopes are stored in dictionaries and the smaller the dictionary is the (marginally) faster the access will be. Since dictionaries are implemented as hashsets the lookup performance is O(1).

Whenever you try to access a variable Python will walk the scopes in this order:

- Local. The local namespace which is the current function scope.
- Enclosing function locals. Depending on the amount of nested functions/lambda's there can be more of these.
- Global. The global scope which is just another dictionary (which you can access through `globals()`)
- Built-ins. The standard Python built-ins that are available in all scopes such as `list`, `int`, etc..

Accessing a function/class attribute works in a similar fashion but involves:

- `__getattribute__`
- `__dict__`
- `__getattr__`

And that over all inherited classes as well.

The rest of your question was answered perfectly by Duncan